# d3.js add second label to bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

2 part question:

I have a bar chart with created using multiple arrays. These arrays contain the % wins of baseball teams; the relevant team colours; and their names.

I can create one set of labels on the chart, either the names or the win %. However I can't get both on at the same time. See below. 
[image: win%]

[image: Team names]

The code I am using is:

```
let WinsLabel = svgContainer.selectAll("text")
    .data(d3.zip(TeamArray, WinPercArray, Colours));    

WinsLabel.enter()
    .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return 45 + (i * 50);
        })
        .attr("y", 700)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("x", function(d,i){
            return 70 + (i*50);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d){
            return 685 - d[1];
        })
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "15px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .text(function(d){
            return d[1]/10 + "%";
        });
```

```
let TeamLabel = svgContainer.selectAll("text")
    .data(d3.zip(TeamArray, WinPercArray, Colours));

TeamLabel.enter()
    .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return 45 + (i * 50);
        })
        .attr("y", 700)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("x", function(d,i){
            return 70 + (i*50);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d){
            return 700 - d[1]/2;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "15px")
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .text(function(d){
            return d[0];
        });
```

When I run the code with both scripts, only the win % shows up, but the names don't. In order to get the names to show up I have to remove the first label.

The 2 parts to my question are:

1. How would I get both sets of labels to show up at the same time?
2. How can I get the names to be arranged vertically in the rectangles/bars?

Comment: The issue lies with `.selectAll("text")`, the 1st time you enter labels, there are no text elements selected so all are entered. The 2nd time, you select the same number of text elements (the first set of labels) as there are items in the data array, as such none are entered. `.enter()` creates elements from items in the data array only where corresponding elements are not present in the selection already. Just use `selectAll(null)`, or if you want to update the text at some point use (and apply) a class name to identify which elements are which type of label: `selectAll(".name")`

Comment: So, from what you are saying, I can't have a 2 labels on the chart at the same time. It's one or the other.

Comment: No, you can have as many labels as you want for each item in the data array - but you won't enter anything if you reselect the old text - you'll just end up assigning new data to the existing labels and the enter selection will be empty. If you use `selectAll(null).data...` you won't select anything so everything is entered. But, this text is hard to reselect if you need to update. If you use `selectAll(".label").data(data).enter().append("text").attr("class","label")` you can select specific text, while still adding as many labels as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3 stands for data driven something; and it's core principle is based on linking elements / selection, with data. When you set data, (`var selection = selectAll(...).data(...)`), you get 3 cases to think about:

1. Some existing elements can be linked to certain item in new data. You access them using `selection`
2. Some elements cannot be linked to any item in new data. You access them using `selection.exit()`
3. Some items in new data cannot be linked to any element from selection. You access them by using `selection.enter()`

In its simplest case, the linking between data and elements is made by index -- ie first element in selection is linked with first item in data array, second with second, and so on. The d3 cannot find element for the data item (= gets put into `.enter()` selection) if and only if (in this by-index context) the index of that data item is bigger than the size of the selection.

On your initial select

```
let WinsLabel = svgContainer.selectAll("text")
.data(d3.zip(TeamArray, WinPercArray, Colours));
```

The selection is empty, since there are no text tags yet. And since its empty, all of the to-be-created placeholders are inside `.enter()` selection. However, on your next select for the other label type

```
let TeamLabel = svgContainer.selectAll("text")
 .data(d3.zip(TeamArray, WinPercArray, Colours));
```

The selection is of the size of the passed data, and thus `.enter()` selection is empty; it's the `TeamLabel` selection that contains all of the old elements (percentage label `text` tags), but they got their data values reassigned.

---

Andrew proposed one solution to assign classes, but personally I'd take all elements that relate to same team and put it under one group.

```js
var TeamArray = ["Yankees",  "Rays", "RedSox", "Jays","Orioles", "Twin", "Indians", "WhiteSox", "Detroit", "Royals", "Astros", "Rangers", "A's", "Angels","Mariners"];
var WinPercArray = [653, 609, 540, 400, 300, 667, 521, 458, 383, 347, 660, 511, 500, 458, 442];
var Colours = ["#003087", "#092C5C", "#BD3039", "#134A8E", "#DF4601", "#002B5C", "#0C2340", "#C4CED4", "#FA4616", "#BD9B60", "#EB6E1F", "#C0111F", "#003831", "#003263", "#005C5C"];

var data = d3.zip(TeamArray, WinPercArray, Colours);

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('height', 300).attr('width', 800);

var teams = svg.selectAll('g.teams')
  .data(data);

var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1000])
  .range([200, 0]);

var teamsEnter = teams.enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('team', true)
  .attr('transform', function(d, i){
    return 'translate(' + (i*50) + ',0)';
  })
  
teamsEnter.append('rect')
   .attr('width', 50)
   .attr('y', function(d) { return scale(d[1]); })
   .attr('height', function(d) { return scale(0) - scale(d[1]); })
   .style('fill', function(d) { return d[2]; });
   
teamsEnter.append('text')
   .attr('x', 25)
   .attr('y', function(d) { return scale(d[1]) - 30; })
   .text(function(d){ return d[0]; });

teamsEnter.append('text')
   .attr('x', 25)
   .attr('y', function(d) { return scale(d[1]) - 15; })
   .text(function(d){ return d[1]; });
```

```css
text {
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Groups in some way act as encapsulation of inner items, so you can mentally separate data binding to groups (ie when to create / update / delete it), from actual logic that takes place when working with its children

Comment: Thanks, that is brilliant